# addExpressionAttributeToSelect add to Magento CatalogSearch

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I will try to add `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` to a magento collection.
When I try this line, it works perfectly:

```
// lat lng of Mallorca, Balearen, Spain
$lat = 39.695263;
$lng = 3.017571;
$dst = 250;
$mile2km = 1.609344;

echo "<pre>";
$col = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->$this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('latlngdistance', "ROUND(
    DEGREES(
        ACOS(
            SIN(RADIANS( $lat )) * SIN(RADIANS( {{lat}} ))
            +  COS(RADIANS( $lat )) * COS(RADIANS( {{lat}} ))
            * COS(RADIANS( $lng - {{lng}} ))
        ) * 60 * 1.1515
    ) * $mile2km
, 1)", array('lat', 'lng'));
        $this->getSelect()->having('latlngdistance <= ?', $dst);
$col->getSelect()->limit(10);
$col->load();
```

But when I add these methods to my collection within a Block, Magento removes my `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` completely

Error Result:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'latlngdistance' in 'having clause'
```

(I've added this method in the Block_Layer, Method: Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection)

Edit:
You have to Edit the "getSelectCountSql" Method

Edit2:
My Final Solution in the rewirte-Collection Class (in My Modul)
So it works with Flat and EAV Tables. so i got the correct number of items.

```
/**
 * Get SQL for get record count
 *
 * @param bool $resetLeftJoins
 * @return Varien_Db_Select
 */
protected function _getSelectCountSql($select = null, $resetLeftJoins = true)
{
    $countSelect = parent::_getSelectCountSql($select, $resetLeftJoins);
    if($this->getDirectCurPage() == 1)
    {
        $mile2km = $this->mile2km;

        $lat = $this->lat;
        $lng = $this->lng;

        $_col_lat = 'e.lat';
        $_col_lng = 'e.lng';
        if(!$this->isEnabledFlat()) // if flat tables did work
        {
            $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
            ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('in', array('lat', 'lng')));

            $tables = array();
            $attribute_ids = array();
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
            {
                $attribute_ids[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getId();
                $tables[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getBackendTable();
            }
            $_col_lat = 'pd_lat.value';
            $_col_lng = 'pd_lng.value';
            $countSelect->join(array('pd_lat' => $tables['lat']),
                    "e.entity_id = pd_lat.entity_id AND pd_lat.attribute_id = {$attribute_ids['lat']}", array());
            $countSelect->join(array('pd_lng' => $tables['lng']),
                    "e.entity_id = pd_lng.entity_id AND pd_lng.attribute_id = {$attribute_ids['lng']}", array());
        }

        $countSelect->columns('COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) as count');
        $countSelect->columns(array('latlngdistance' => new Zend_Db_Expr("ROUND(
            DEGREES(
                ACOS(
                    SIN(RADIANS( $lat )) * SIN(RADIANS( {$_col_lat} ))
                    +  COS(RADIANS( $lat )) * COS(RADIANS( {$_col_lat} ))
                    * COS(RADIANS( $lng - {$_col_lng} ))
                ) * 60 * 1.1515
            ) * $mile2km
        , 1)")));
        $countSelect->group('latlngdistance');
        $OldcountSelect = $countSelect;
        $countSelect = $this->getConnection()->select();
        $countSelect->from(array('a' => $OldcountSelect), array('SUM(a.count)'));
        unset($OldcountSelect);
    }
    return $countSelect;
}
```

Comment: Check this answer. It seams the problem described in the question is similar to yours: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6310/146

Comment: please don't include the answer in the question. Add an answer to your own question and remove the answer from the question.